# Что означает конструкция static {...}

Tags: java

Как понимать конструкцию `static {...}`, находится в классе:

```
class test {
    static {
    ...
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

В *Java* существует такое понятие, как статические инициализаторы. Статические инициализаторы — это методы, предназначенные для инициализации переменных класса, то есть переменных, описанных как `static`. Статические инициализаторы автоматически вызываются системой, когда класс загружается, поэтому они не могут иметь параметров и не возвращают значения. Кроме того, у метода нет имени. Что же остается? Ключевое слово `static` и фигурные скобки.

```
public class Circle {
static private double sines[] = new double[1000];
static private double cosines[] = new double[1000];
static {
     double x, delta_x;
     int i;
     delta_x = (Math.PI/2)/(1000-1);
     for(i = 0, x = 0.0; i < 1000; i++, x += delta_x) {
         sines[i] = Math.sin(x);   cosines[i] = Math.cos(x);
     }
}
}
```

Внутри одного класса может встретиться любое число таких статических инициализаторов. Статический инициализатор выполняется только один раз, когда такой класс впервые загружен.