# Есть ли разница когда инициализировать значение переменной?

Tags: java

Пока не очень силен в синтаксисе java.
Нашел вот такой пример:

```
private static int CARS_COUNT;

static {

    CARS_COUNT = 0;
}
```

Есть ли существенное различие, если я напишу так?:

```
private static int CARS_COUNT = 0;
```

В плане возможностей работы с данной переменной

Answer (score 5):

Пожалуй, следует дополнить предыдущий ответ.

Следует понимать, что сами по себе `static`-поля хранятся в специальном месте кучи (`heap`) памяти `java`. Там есть своеобразный пул значений, которые могут часто использоваться (как раз таки одно из назначений статик поля - задание констант). Поэтому эти значения загружаются в это место в памяти самыми первыми.

В таком случае, статические инициализаторы выполняются единожды при загрузке программы в память. Причем все происходит в прямом порядке: в том, который написан прямо в тексте программы.

Так как в нашем случае поле `int` ( а это примитивный тип данных), то и в память загрузится `0`. После этого в память загрузится `U`, в которую присвоено значение `0`. И только после этого выполнится статический инициализатор и `I` получит значение равное `5`.
Если поменять местами так, то выведется значение равное `5`:

```
public class MyClass {

    static int I;

    static {
        I = 5;
    }
    
    //static блок ещё не выполнился поэтому I=0;
    static int U = I;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("U = " + U); // выведет 5
    }
}
```

Что касаемо исходного примера, то разницы не будет, если то `static`-инициализатора это поле не использовалось. Успехов!

Answer (score 4):

Разница есть. В первом варианте до выполнения `static` блока переменная будет иметь значение по умолчанию. Если её использовать до выполнения `static` блока - будет использовано значение по умолчанию.

```
public class MyClass {

    static int I;
    
    //static блок ещё не выполнился поэтому I=0;
    static int U = I;
    
    static {
        I = 5;
    }
    
    //а вот тут уже static блок выполнился и U будет равно 5
    // static int U = I;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("U = " + U); // выведет 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Немного про примитивы и значение по умолчанию

Тип `int` - примитивный тип данных. Переменная этого типа не ссылается на какой-то класс, а просто *хранит в себе какое-либо значение*. И когда вы не даёте никакого значения примитиву, то ему присваивается *значение по умолчанию* (для типа `int` это `0`).

То эта запись

```java
private static int CARS_COUNT;
```

даст тот же результат, что и эта:

```java
private static int CARS_COUNT = 0;
```

#### А теперь разберём ваш пример

```java
private static int CARS_COUNT; //Переменная имеет значение по умолчанию, т.е 0

static {

    CARS_COUNT = 0; //Вы присваиваете переменной то же самое значение, какое у неё и было
}
```

В данном случае статический инициализатор ничего не меняет. Но вы могли сделать так, как уже говорил `@ЮрийСПб♦`. Вы же могли в статическом инициализаторе присвоить переменной другое значение (не ноль):

```java
 static {
      CARS_COUNT = 11;  
 }
```

тогда бы переменная имела бы значение `11`, а не `0`.

#### Но если статической переменной можно сразу дать нужное значение, то зачем конструкция `static{}`?

Представьте, что у вас не статическая переменная типа `int`, а статический массив. Да, вы конечно можете сделать так:

```
static int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Но если вам нужно заполнить массив не заранее известными числами, а числами, которые возвращают какие-то методы? А если в массиве `100` элементов и их надо заполнить циклом? В таком случае вам поможет статический инициализатор. Вот пример:

```java
int[] array = new int[100];
 
static{
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
         j++;
         array[i] = j;
    }
}
```

Можно посмотреть ответ на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320507/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-static) вопрос, если хотите узнать больше о конструкции `static{}`